# How can i make a Regex such that is should allow only 2 characters M or F

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I would like to valid a string if it consists of `M` or `F`. If possible i would also like to know if some one enters `Male` or `Female` i would like to get the result as `M` or `F`.. But my first case is to check whether the string has `M` or `F`. In any other character i would like to make my result as false.

Comment: I'll offset it for you. It's a valid question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this -

```
var match = Regex.Match("M", @"^M(ale)?$|^F(emale)?$");
var result = match.Success;
```

Comment: How can i include my string here `Match match = Regex.Match(strGender,"M", @"^M(ale)?$|$F(emale)?^");`

Comment: `"M"` is just an example string in my code, so you'd need to do `Regex.Match(strGender, @"^M(ale)?$|$F(emale)?^");`

Answer (score 4):

If there are only 4 valid choices, then I reccomend you not use regex. You could use an extension method:

```
public static bool InList<T>(this T item, params T[] list)
{
    return list.Contains(item);
}
```

Then in your code you could use:

```
myString.InList("M", "Male", "F", "Female")
```

That would return TRUE if it was one of the four choices. After you validate the gender, you could just grab the first letter using .SubString().

Comment: Why not. Regexps can be compiled into efficient C code (finite state machines) that are much faster in matching than list operations. They will likely stop after reading the first or second character already and not even look at the full string.

Comment: Several reasons: Maintainability, readability, and expandability. For something so simple, regex is overly-complicated. There may be side-cases that sneak through the regex, while a list of 4 small words is direct and easy to manage, especially if the OP wants to later add another option (like OTHER or NOT SPECIFIED, etc.). The amount of work needed to make that change is too much in the regex approach to justify it (speed is a non-issue for either method in this case).

Comment: A regexp like "^(M|Male|F|Female)$" is not at all hard to maintain, or read... I don't think many new _genders_ will be discovered anytime soon.

Comment: Regex is traditionally used to match patterns, not to check if a word matches 4 other ones. To each his own, though - the beauty of programming is that there are always several ways to do things. I'm mearly pointing out that this is not a case where one would nessesarily settle on regex.

Comment: Well, regexp is a shorthand notion to specify finite automatons to match strings, and that is what he's trying to do: match strings. A finite state machine can of course do difficult cases, but it does also simple cases very well. In particular when compiled into native code, it will essentially produce just a few if and return statements that execute at maximum CPU efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Use the regexp `^(M|Male|F|Female)$` in ignore-case mode, if it matches, get the first character and uppercase it. Precompile the regexp to get an efficient finite state machine. The result will then be machine code like this:

```
if s[0] == 'M':
  if s[1] == \0: return True
  if s[1] != 'a': return False
  if s[2] != 'l': return False
  if s[3] != 'e': return False
  if s[4] == \0: return True
  return False
if s[0] == 'F':
  if s[1] == \0: return True
  if s[1] != 'e': return False
  if s[2] != 'm': return False
  if s[3] != 'a': return False
  if s[4] != 'l': return False
  if s[5] != 'e': return False
  if s[6] == \0: return True
  return False
return False
```

Hard to beat this in the number of CPU cycles.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking at this wrong.

What you need is a drop-down list or a couple of radio-buttons constraining the user's choices and returning exactly the data you want.

Otherwise, your users will have problems with your software. Some will make typos, some may type a space after the word, some of them will use a "." after M or F because it's an abbreviation. Additionally, you need to explain that you want them to write M or F. Users don't read, so anything which requires an explanation is an annoyance.

A question with one answer only out of a few possible answers should be asked with a radio button or a drop down list.

If you really want the user to write M or F, note that none of the previous answers posted allow you to get "m" or "f" as the result if the user writes "Male" or "Female". If you go that route, you need something like this:

```
your_string.toUpper();
if (your_string.contains("M", "MALE", "F", "FEMALE"))
{
   switch (your_string)
   {
       case "M":
          return "M";
       case "Male":
          return "M";
       case "F":
          return "F";
       case "Female":
          return "M";
       default:
          return false;
    }
}
```

This works, but it's much better to use the right UI tools for the job.

Comment: I am reading data from my `excel` file that's why i would like to go for `Regex`

Comment: Oups! That's the kind of details you might want to mention in the question brief, though.